# Get user input during installation using setup project and use it in installer

Tags: .net, winforms, service, setup-project

I have created an installer to install a windows service. Installer should ask user to name the service. Hence, I have created a custom UI in the installer with `TextBox`.

When user runs the setup.exe file, installation starts and the custom UI shows up. User adds the name for the windows service but how shall I take the `ServiceName` as user input during installation and set default service name into service name provided by user during installation in that custom UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to follow these steps:

1. Create a Windows *Service project*. It will create a service project containing `Service1.cs`.
2. Open `Service1.cs` and right click and choose *Add Installer*. It will create a `ProjectInstaller.cs`.
3. Add a new *Setup Project*.  (If you don't have project template, download and install it from here for [VS2013](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=UnniRavindranathan-MSFT.MicrosoftVisualStudio2013InstallerProjects), [VS2015](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudio2015InstallerProjects) or [VS2017](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects))
4. Add primary output of the service project to the setup project.
5. Go to *User Interface* window and a new Dialog using *TextBoxes (A)* template after *Installation Folder*. (Set visible property of other textboxes than `Edit1` to `false`.)
6. Go to *Custom Actions* window and add a new custom action from primary output of the service project.
7. In the *Custom Action* window, go to this node go to this node *Custom Actions* → *Install* → *Primary outputfrom WindowsService1* and in *Properties* window, set the value of `CustomActionData` to `/SVCNAME=[EDITA1]`.
8. Open `ProjectInstaller.cs` in your service project and override `Install` to set `Name` or `DisplayName` of the service:

   ```
   public override void Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
   {
       string value = Context.Parameters["SVCNAME"];
       this.serviceInstaller1.DisplayName = value;
       base.Install(stateSaver);
   }
   ```

Then build your projects and install the service.